# OpenGL: Render to framebuffer as well as to display

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math, fbo

I have a 3d scene which I can render on my display. However, in addition to rendering it to display, I would like to also be able to export the rendered scene, say once every 100 frames, as a image (say a JPG or PNG image), maybe saving it as a file somewhere on my machine.

I tried something like the following:

```
do{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffername);
    drawScene();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    drawScene();
}while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the FrameBuffer Objects correctly, but was looking for suggestions as to how to proceed given my goal. From the above code, I am binding the framebuffer to the FBO I have defined and then drawing the scene (which should draw to the FBO if I am correct?). Then I draw again to my regular display. However, this code causes the display to constantly switch between my scene, and an empty (black) scene, which I don't want. I want my scene to be displayed to the display device as a nice clean 3d scene, without constantly going all black.

My drawing function looks something like this:

```
void drawScene() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
//glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffername);

// Use our shader
glUseProgram(programID);

// Compute the MVP matrix from keyboard and mouse input
computeMatricesFromInputs();
glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0); //DEFINE MODEL TO WORLD TRANSFORMATION
                                        //glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::scale(2.0,2.0,2.0);
glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

// Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
// in the "MVP" uniform
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
glUniform1f(FARPLANE, farplane_control);
glUniform1f(NEARPLANE, nearplane_control);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);
glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(0, 0, 4);
glUniform3f(LightID, lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);

// 1st attribute buffer : vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    0,                  // attribute
    3,                  // size
    GL_FLOAT,           // type
    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
    0,                  // stride
    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
);

// 2nd attribute buffer : normals
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    1,                                // attribute
    3,                                // size
    GL_FLOAT,                         // type
    GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
    0,                                // stride
    (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
);

// Draw the triangle !
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (GLsizei)vertices.size());

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);

// Swap buffers
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `drawScene()` code includes these lines at the end:

```
// Swap buffers
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
```

What do you think happens if you call this when you're not actually rendering to the screen?

The obvious solution is to include a flag in the function that instructs whether to perform the buffer swapping:

```
void drawScene(bool swap = true) {
    /*...*/
    if(swap) {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

do{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffername);
    drawScene(false);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    drawScene(true);
}while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS
```

Or, you could move those calls outside the function, which is probably better since it doesn't really make sense to make them local to your draw function in the first place.

```
do{
    glfwPollEvents(); //Prefer having this be the first call, in case you need the window
    //responding to user input immediately
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffername);
    drawScene();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    drawScene();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window); //No longer in drawScene() function
}while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS
```

Comment: @user308485 Please Upvote and accept the answer if it works for you.